# Sound not working until switching audio profiles

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a weird issue with my Arch Linux install.
When the computer hasn't been playing audio for a while, it refuses to do so until I open up my audio panel and switch the audio profile to something else, and then back to the one I want to use.
For example, I have to switch from "Analog Stereo Duplex" to "Analog Stereo Output" and then back to "Analog Stereo Duplex".
When starting at "Analog Stereo Output", just switching to "Analog Stereo Duplex" also fixes the problem. But neither "Output" nor "Duplex" work right out of the gate, both require some from of switching.
Before doing this switch, sound refuses to play, and most applications that try just hang at 0 seconds until I switch. For example, Youtube refuses to show the video at all (just a loading spinner).

Hardware is ASRock DeskMini X300.

I also have a display with speakers connected to the machine, but it doesn't play any sound in the meantime either, and permanently setting it's profile to "Off" also made no difference.

Here's some terminal output that might be of use:

```
  ~ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 2: ALC233 Alt Analog [ALC233 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
➜  ~ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [AG271QG4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC233 Analog [ALC233 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
➜  ~ /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_seq                94208  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_seq
snd_hda_codec_realtek   172032  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     86016  1
snd_hda_intel          61440  7
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         188416  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core          118784  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               172032  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   131072  26 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
➜  ~
```

Neither `alsactl kill rescan` nor  `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/pulseold && killall pulseaudio` solve the problem.
Anything else I can try, or any other interesting logs I could look at to narrow down the issue?

Here is a screen recording of the issue in action:

https://streamable.com/bjzyij

Answer (score 1):

The solution was provided to me by a friendly user of the archlinux forums.

To quote the person who helped me:

> You are mixing wireplumber and pulseaudio which is an
> unsupported/expected to be troublesome configuration. Either switch to
> pipewire-media-session and keep pulseaudio or switch to pipewire
> properly by installing pipewire-pulse instead of pulseaudio.